# TypeError: Fetch failed in SvelteKit server-side rendering - Express does not show a proper TypeScript stack trace

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, svelte, sveltekit

I am checking the logs of the SvelteKit SSR server using [adapter-node](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node).

I have customised the `server.js` to use [Express instead of Polka](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/scripts/server.js), though not sure if this matters.

There are apparent errors which I believe is when `fetch()` tries to read data from backend API and fails for some reason.

This is the console output from I get using `docker`:

```
frontend  | TypeError: fetch failed
frontend  |     at fetch (file:///app/build/handler.js:17895:14)
frontend  |     at async Object.fetch (file:///app/build/server/index.js:2273:12)
frontend  |     at async fetch (file:///app/build/server/index.js:991:24)
frontend  |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
frontend  |     at async load (file:///app/build/server/chunks/6-0becfa88.js:8:56)
frontend  |     at async load_data (file:///app/build/server/index.js:1088:16)
frontend  |     at async file:///app/build/server/index.js:1887:18
```

This stack trace is unusable, because it lacks the information of what was the function / source code that called `fetch()`. Not sure if this is because of how Node.js / Express works, or because lack of TypeScript source map support in some part of the stack or something else. A SvelteKit project has dozens of functions called `load()` because that is what every router endpoint has.

What would be a way to make these errors, and SvelteKit error handling in general, more descriptive - e.g. to show the proper caller mapped to its TypeScript source file, the failed page name, failed URL in `fetch()` and so on? This would then help to diagnose the underlying problem of what could be wrong with the API calls that fail.

Comment: This has been a bit of a pain point for me as well. Debugging the built code for Node.js is pretty tricky. You can comb through the built code and you might find some esbuild tags that could point you in the right direction.

Comment: async is a tool of a devil and the root cause of undebuggabilty. However, SvelteKit is now 1.0 and more and more people face this issue. Well-known or de facto standard solutions should be developing as we speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be lacking of **sourcemap**.

When SvelteKit builds your app, it gonna split your code into several chunks which makes unusable error stack trace.

There is a way to enable sourcemap again and you can try that on your project to see if it works.

1. Modify `vite.config.xx` file, add below config:

```
const config = {
  ...
  build:{
    sourcemap: true // Config vite to generate sourcemap when bundling.
  },
  ...
}
```

2. Add `sourcemap` flag when starting node, for example:

```
node index.js --enable-source-maps
```

This should make your stack trace pointing to your `src` instead of `build`. You can try and check out whether your project is still printing unmeaningful stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an open issue with Vite (and thus SvelteKit) that prevents source maps from being loaded: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3288

Comment:  oh snap - manual logging decoration it is then

Comment: That issue is about debugging. Server-side runtime stack traces use source maps just fine for me. I didn't need to specifically enable them in `vite.config` (that controls generation of client-side source maps), but I did need to put the `--enable-source-maps` *before* the script name, i.e.: `node --enable-source-maps build/`

Answer (score 3):

You can define [`handleFetch()`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch) inside  `src/hooks.server.ts`. Then log both the requested URL and page from there:

```
// src/hooks.server.js

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').HandleFetch} */
export function handleFetch({ event, request, fetch }) {

  let fetchResult;
  try {
      fetchResult = await fetch(request);
  } catch (error) {
      // Log info from event and request here.
  }

  return fetchResult;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Leftium. This is quite excessive logging. Would you know if there is more generic solution available that would simply show the descriptive stack trace where the fetch() failed?

Comment: You can wrap `fetch()` in a try block and only log when it fails. I updated my answer. If fetch() doesn't throw an error, just check for the error status and log accordingly. @MikkoOhtamaa

Answer (score 1):

Check Your server's environment variable, did you put NODE_ENV = 'production' on the server, it could be expecting that but got 'development' instead therefor the url will http://localhost which will cause fetch error